# ORA-00933: SQL when I try to refresh a Materialized View

Tags: oracle, materialized-views, ora-00933

When I try and run the following refresh for a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`

```
ALTER materialized VIEW table_name.materialized_view_name refresh FORCE START 
WITH trunc(SYSDATE, 'HH24') + 2/24 NEXT SYSDATE + 6/24;
```

I'm getting `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`, however I am unable to see how it is not properly ended

Comment: Is this the only statement in the batch?

Comment: yep, that's the only statement

Comment: Which tool do you use to run that? Maybe it's confused by the `/`

Comment: I'm running toad

Comment: Your question says `table_name.materialized_view_name`. Are you actually giving it the name of a table, or do you mean schema?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I'm using the schema name not a table name.